# Можно ли в SFML2 из sf::Text создать sf::Texture

Tags: c++, sfml, текстура

Существует ли в библиотеке SFML2 функция которая из `sf::Text` создёт `sf::Texture` ?

Comment: render to texture?

Comment: @VTT, не понял. Что это за функция и как её вызвать?